# How can I go back to native view controller from react-native page?

Tags: back, react-native

I wrapped a react-native page with a `UIViewController`, and pushed it with a navigation controller, but how can I pop to the native page using the react-native js code?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to have a property that references your `UIViewController` on your `AppDelegate` and have a React Native Module method (`RCT_EXPORT`) that calls `dismissViewController` or `presentViewController`, based on your situation.

I would recommend reading this post discussing combining native iOS Views and React Native here: [Leverage Existing iOS Views with React Native](http://moduscreate.com/leverage-existing-ios-views-react-native-app/)