# Dismiss a React Native RCTRootView back to a Native ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm creating an app to integrate `react-native` with an existing Swift app.

I've looked into similar issues:

- [React-Native: Dismiss/Exit React-Native View back to Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298144/react-native-dismiss-exit-react-native-view-back-to-native)
- [How can I go back to native view controller from react-native page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30626301/how-can-i-go-back-to-native-view-controller-from-react-native-page)

While following different tutorials:

- [React Native calling class methods on native Swift](https://medium.com/@jjdanek/react-native-calling-class-methods-on-native-swift-views-521faf44f3dc)
- [Swift in React Native the ultimate guide](https://teabreak.e-spres-oh.com/swift-in-react-native-the-ultimate-guide-part-1-modules-9bb8d054db03)
- [React Native tutorial integrating in an existing app](https://www.raywenderlich.com/945-react-native-tutorial-integrating-in-an-existing-app#toc-anchor-004)*

And the official [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.60/navigation)

The problem is: all of them are outdated (but the docs). Most of them use the legacy `Navigation` rather than `Stack Navigator`. One of the tutorials (the one with an asterisk) shows how to dismiss the React Native app back to the Native app using the `rootTag` of the app, but again, this was done with the legacy `Navigation`.

If I try to do the same, I'm not able to see the `props` from my app.

I have a single Storyboard with a `Button` inside that when clicked calls this `UIViewController`:

**ButtonController**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import React

class ButtonController: UIViewController  {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        let data:[String : String] = ["onNavigationStateChange": "{handleNavigationChange}",
                                      "uriPrefix":"/app"];
        let rootView = MixerReactModule.sharedInstance.viewForModule("ReactNativeApp", initialProperties: data)

        let viewController = UIViewController()
        viewController.view = rootView
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And when I start the app I can see this:

```
2019-10-23 10:29:30.021 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Running "ReactNativeApp" with {"rootTag":1,"initialProps":{"uriPrefix":"/app","onNavigationStateChange":"{handleNavigationChange}"}}
```

But when I try to access the `this.props` property on React Native code I get `undefined`.

**index.js**

```
import HomeScreen from './components/HomeScreen'
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen}
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home'
})

const NavigationApp = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ReactNativeApp', () => NavigationApp)

console.log("NANANA1", this)
console.log("NANANA2", this.routeName)
console.log("NANANA3", MainNavigator)
console.log("NANANA4", MainNavigator.props)
console.log("NANANA5", NavigationApp)
console.log("NANANA6", NavigationApp.props)

export default NavigationApp
```

**HomeScreen.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button, NativeModules} from 'react-native';

var RNBridge = NativeModules.RNBridge;

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      headerTitle: () => (
        <Text>'Welcome'</Text>
      ),
      headerLeft: () => (
        <Button title="Dismiss" onPress={() => {
          console.log("WOLOLO: ", RNBridge)
          console.log("ROGAN: ", this._reactInternalFiber.tag)
          RNBridge.dismissPresentedViewController(this._reactInternalFiber.tag)
          // RNBridge.dismissPresentedViewController(1)
        }}/>
      )
    };
    render() {
      console.log('KIKIKI', this._reactInternalFiber.tag)
      console.log("MMMMMMM: ", this.props)
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Home Screen</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
}
```

These are the 2 files that I use in RN to generate my View. I've tried many things to get the `rootTag` value, and the only one that seems to provide this value is (`tag` and `rootTag` on XCode are the same (`1`))

```
this._reactInternalFiber.tag
```

But I don't know how to send these values to my `headerLeft` method to use the same tag so that when I press the `Dismiss` button it calls the Swift code for `dismissPresentedViewController`.

How can I dismiss my VC effectively? Or at least get the `rootTag` being passed from Swift to my `headerLeft()` method?

I'm using these versions of `react-native`:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.2
```

Comment: Why don't you dismiss the RN View Controller from the Native Header itself? I mean, render the header in Native if it's not going to change and clear the View from the Swift file.

Comment: Could you post an example on how would you do it? I think I'm kinda lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are looking to dismiss the native swift view controller presented from RN View

```swift
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I present the swift view controller as below

```swift
 let modelVC = ModelViewController()  <-- sub class of UIViewController

 DispatchQueue.main.async {
   let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: modelVC)
   navController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
   let topController = UIApplication.topMostViewController()
   topController?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
```

I have an extension on the UIApplication to find out what is the top most view controller which is used above

```swift
extension UIApplication {

  class func topMostViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
      return topMostViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
    }

    if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
      if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
        return topMostViewController(controller: selected)
      }
    }

    if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
      return topMostViewController(controller: presented)
    }

    return controller
  }
}
```

Comment: I got busy with something else, but let me give it a try over the weekend